# Can stars be observed from space by x-rays, near infrared and radio wavelengths?

Tags: star, spectroscopy, wavelength

I have a doubt.

Can stars be observed from space by x-rays, near infrared and radio wavelengths?

Comment: No, "seen" implies the human eye, which is incapable of sensing in these wavelengths. Or didn't you mean that?

Comment: In the fantastic [chromoscope](http://www.chromoscope.net/) you can simply slide-choose what wavelength you want to see the Milky Way at. But stars are only part of what generates this. There are compact objects, gas and dust too. And even icy comets emit x-rays when the solar wind interacts with the coma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and not only from space but from the Earth surface too. Stars emit in almost all wavelengths depending on their surface temperatures. The hotter the star is the shorter (higher energy) wavelengths it'll emit.

You can try this simulator to check this:

http://astro.unl.edu/naap/blackbody/animations/blackbody.html

Comment: The surface temperature of a star (unless possibly a neutron star) has little to do with its X-ray emission (or its radio emission). You have also got Wien's law the wrong way around, unless by higher you mean shorter?

Comment: Even the Sun emits in X-ray, at least it's hottest spots and Corona. Thanks for the correction about Wien's law, I editted my answer.

Comment: So are you saying that hot stars emit a larger fraction of their light at X-ray wavelengths? Because that is not the case. And most of the radio emission is non-thermal.